# tuneRF and stepFactor problems

Tags: r, random-forest

I feel uncomfortable with the meaning of stepFactor parameter of tuneRF function which is used for tuning the mtry parameter used futher in randomforest function (R program).

The documentation of the `tuneRf` function says that `stepFactor` is a magnitude by which the chosen `mtry` gets deflated or inflated. Obviously, sisnce `mtry` is a number of variables chosen randomly, it has to be intetger, however I saw many examples on the net using `stepFactor=1.5`. At first I thought that R uses by deflault next `mtry` equal to `floor(mtry_current-stepFactor)`, but it turned out that not at all was I right. Moreover I do not understand the R commands displaying search left... search right... while `tuneRF` function is working. I thought it was the information on either inflating or deflating the `mtry` parameter, but my suppositions did not turn out to be correct.

To sum up this long and not too graceful description of my doubts, my questions are:

- Why is stepFactor NOT an integer number?
- How are subsequent mtry values chosen?
- What does searching left/right actually mean?

Comment: not clear: mtry is not chosen randomly, it is mtry=if (!is.null(y) && !is.factor(y))
max(floor(ncol(x)/3), 1) else floor(sqrt(ncol(x))

Answer (score -1):

Awful argument! It seems that at each iteration `mtryStart` gets multiplied by `stepFactor`. Greater help from a simple cycle where `mtry`is increased by 1.

```
set.seed(1)
tuning<-vector(length =(ncol(iris)-1))
for (i in 1:(ncol(iris)-1)) {
    irisRF<-randomForest(x=iris[,-5],mtry = i,iris$Species, ntree = 100);
    tuning[i]<-irisRF$err.rate[100,1];
}

plot(x=1:(ncol(iris)-1), y=tuning, ylab="OOBError", xlab="mtry value", type='b')
```

[image]